# Error: Cannot find package 'babel-plugin-transform-class-properties' importe from.... C: \

Tags: maven, babeljs, babel-plugin

When I run my maven project which execute npm build I always get this error. I have been updating all my dependencies to babel 7. My package json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "test": "jest --coverage --config ./jest.config.js",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --runInBand",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "test:watchAll": "npm run test -- --watchAll",
    "test:updateSnapshot": "jest --updateSnapshot"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "6.26.0",
    "dom-to-image": "2.6.0",
    "i18n-react": "0.6.4",
    "immutable": "^4.0.0-rc.12",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "mime-types": "latest",
    "prop-types": "latest",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-select": "3.0.4",
    "react-svg": "^10.0.14",
    "react-webcam": "^5.2.0",
    "reactjs-popup": "^1.4.2",
    "redux": "4.2.0",
    "redux-logger": "3.0.6",
    "redux-promise-middleware": "6.1.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.0",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.11.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-class-properties": "^7.23.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^7.24.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.23.3",
    "@babel/preset-stage-0": "^7.8.3",
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-react-html-attrs": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-rewire": "^1.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^7.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.2",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.2",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.4.3",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.4.0",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "less": "^4.0.0",
    "less-loader": "^6.1.3",
    "react-hot-loader": "4.8.4",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^5.0.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.3.0"
  }
}
```

My error is: [INFO] ERROR in ./main.jsx
[INFO] Module build failed (from ../../../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
[INFO] Error: Cannot find package 'babel-plugin-transform-class-properties' imported from C:\.....

The thing is when I execute npm install from terminal never gets any error, it's just when I run mvn install for my module.

How can I solve this issue?

I expect to install maven project with no errors. I have tried to change some dependencies versions but didn't work for me.